# ms sql report builder IsError not showing true

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've a query to show using SSRS and am building it with MS report builder 2014

In the query are one or two fields built from expressions. I've reduced one of these expressions down to `=IsError(fields.x/fields.y)` and, as expected, on the report it shows "False" wherever there isn't a division by zero.

but when there IS an error, it's not showing as True. It's just showing as `#Error`

What could be causing this strange behaviour from something so fundamental? How is this even possible?

Comment: Why don't you check IIF(IsNothing(fields.y) OR fields.y=0,false,true) ?

Also reason is Divide by Zero is already breaking the expression and hence it cannot reach to call IsError.

Comment: This is just me coming from a different background - I thought the whole point of `IsError()` was to catch an error if it was thrown but apparently it's not. (Well it is in, say, an Excel spreadsheet but not in VB)